# How to visit (not download) a page using curl or wget

Tags: curl, wget

I am very new to wget/curl. I am trying to get a page to execute its html/scripts using wget/curl. I do not care about downloading the actual page, just that the scripts on the page run.  Is there a command to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Neither curl nor wget execute JavaScript, you will need to use something like a scripted browser or a web test framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cURL and wget are used to **transfer** files/content to/from a specified location. As such, cURL and wget are neither suitable for actually rendering web pages nor executing JavaScript on those webpages. While cURL can be used to output received data to stdout, it is still not designed to render that data.

If you would like to use the terminal to execute JavaScript within a webpage, you may want to consider looking into [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). PhantomJS can load local HTML files and interact with/execute their JavaScript.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to call a PHP script you can do:

```
curl http://your-domain.com/script.php
```

But with just wget your script will be downloaded:

```
wget http://your-domain.com/script.php
```

But with wget -q -O you can call the script like curl:

```
wget -q -O http://your-domain.com/script.php
```

Comment: `-O` requires a filename as parameter, so the last command will simply show you the `wget` help/usage. To make `wget` output a similar result as `curl example.com` would, you can use `wget -O- example.com`.